# Using Alias keyword to declare a function in VBA

Tags: ms-access, winapi, vb6, vba

I have VBA MS Access form code, where I type the following function declaration:

```
Public Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" () Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
```

However I'm getting an error on `Alias`. Do I have to add some references in order to use this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there are no special libraries are required to use `Alias`; this is all built into the language.

But your declaration is wrong. You have an extra set of parentheses placed just before `Alias` that are confusing the compiler.

Beyond pure syntax, the second parameter (`nSize`) is actually a *pointer* to a `Long`, which means that you need to pass it `ByRef` in VBA.

So the revised declaration would look like this, instead:

```
Public Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" _
        (ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByRef nSize As Long) As Long
```

The return value will be 1 if the function succeeds, or 0 if it fails.

Comment: Declaring an API functino `As Boolean` is an overkill IMO. "Proper" VB booleans are longs constrained to 0/-1 but you can use `CopyMemory` to force any value, non-zero being true. This is what `As Boolean` on the API declare will do -- hide a 1 in a boolean. Using such "hacked" values in bool expressions can have strange side effects like `bValue1 And bValue2` being false on both vars being true.

Comment: @wqw Quite correct. it can also lead to Not bValue being True when bValue is also True. Don't use Boolean in Declare against the Windows API

Comment: VB 6 really doesn't know how to marshal data types any better than that? Yes, it represents boolean data types differently internally than other common programming languages, and `BOOL` in the WinAPI isn't a boolean data type at all. But I've never had a problem making it work as expected. I guess my expectations are artificial. Declare it either way you want; if it's a `Long`, then `TRUE` will be 1 and `FALSE` will be 0.