# Spoofing The UserName Environment Function In Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, command-line, cmd, windows-xp

I've been looking into the Environ function to retrieve the current Windows username inside of Access 2003 on a Windows XP machine (This will be used on Windows 7 as well). The only problem is, is that I stumbled across various articles and forums stating that the variables are very easily spoof-able.

[Here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?357723-Classic-VB-API-How-Do-I-Get-The-Current-Windows-Username) and [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?525810-Environ%28-quot-USERNAME-quot-%29-function&p=3249442#post3249442) for example.

So I decided to run some tests and I tried setting the local variables:

```
SET USERNAME = testUser
```

Would change my username in the command prompt and leave the CMD session open.

I would then run my Access code.

```
findCurrentUsername = Environ("Username")
```

and I would still receive the username I'd expect.

I also tried going to Computer > Properties > Advanced tab, and I could not find the variable there.

Also, this will be used within a class and as such I was having  difficulties importing external libraries.

Is the Environ functional spoof-able inside a corporate environment and if so, how do you do it?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/371382/where-is-username-variable-defined  + youre safe unless youre working with some badass h4x0r$ or malicious users who live to prove your software is not perfect - none is.

Comment: If you're worried about spoofing of the environmental variable, why not just avoid it altogether and use the WinAPI `GetUserName()` function directly instead?

Comment: I considered that, but I don't actually know how to reference the WinAPI's library to call the function inside of a class.

Comment: If you started acceess from that command window you would see the change. The environment is inheirited from the program that starts it. For clicking an access icon it is system and user variables were inheirited by explorer, explorer startes windows installer that gets a copy ofexplorer's environment. Windows Installer checks access is correctly installed and starts it with a copy of it's environment. You can't change another program's environment.

Comment: @DavidCandy I produced your described test and as such found my answer. Thank you. Do you have any alternative that would work within a class?

Comment: The other comments have answered that. Access can have it's own security. But I last set it up 14 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per David Candy's Comment On The Original Question:

I tested by opening the console. I then ran:

```
Set USERNAME=test
```

After running that I found the file path of my MDB and did

```
Start FILEPATH\FILENAME.mdb
```

And ran the Environ("Username") function that returned "test"

A workaround to this is to use the code David Candy left on the comment to this answer:

```
Public Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" 
Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
```

The workaround I used within a class module is(from [HERE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161394)):

I declared the following function-library(You must declare it privately within a class):

```
 Private Declare Function WNetGetUser Lib "mpr.dll" _
  Alias "WNetGetUserA" (ByVal lpName As String, _
  ByVal lpUserName As String, lpnLength As Long) As Long
```

and called it using:

```
' Buffer size for the return string.
  Const lpnLength As Integer = 255

  ' Get return buffer space.
  Dim status As Integer

  ' For getting user information.
  Dim lpName, lpUserName As String

  ' Assign the buffer size constant to lpUserName.
  lpUserName = Space$(lpnLength + 1)

  ' Get the log-on name of the person using product.
  status = WNetGetUser(lpName, lpUserName, lpnLength)

  ' See whether error occurred.
  If status = 0 Then
     ' This line removes the null character. Strings in C are null-
     ' terminated. Strings in Visual Basic are not null-terminated.
     ' The null character must be removed from the C strings to be used
     ' cleanly in Visual Basic.
     findCurrentUsername = Left$(lpUserName, InStr(lpUserName, Chr(0)) - 1)
  Else
    'Backup GetUsername that does not use Windows API, instead it uses local Variables
    findCurrentUsername = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName 'Environ("Username")
  End If
```

Comment: That's not "spoofing" anything. It's changing the environment for the command window inside the same command window, which is perfectly valid and requires no "spoofing" or "hacking". You've changed it in that environment; processes inherit the environment from where they were started. If you open two separate command prompts, type `SET USERNAME=test` into one of them, switch to the other and type `SET USERNAME`, you won't see `test` as the result in that second window.

Comment: Perhaps it was a poorly worded question, but by the word spoof's  definition, you can spoof as another user this way and since the intention was that this was to be used for security, and this proves that this is not a valid solution

Comment: As you can see, that's why I told you to search out how to use the WinAPI `GetUserName` instead. :-) See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5756883) for how to declare it.

Comment: @KenWhite Do you have a suggestion on how to declare a library function from within a class?

Comment: You declare it inside the start of your class declaration (VB.NET code for `PostMessage`, but similar): `Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageW" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, 
ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As IntPtr`, and use it: `Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
  Const WM_NULL As Integer = &H0
  PostMessage(Me.Handle, WM_NULL, 0, 0)
End Sub

Comment: He is using Access which I don't. But Office 2003 is VBA 6. Public Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Comment: @DavidCandy Thanks for the help, I've described my solution as well as your suggestions in the answer.

Comment: @Elias Consider using this: `MsgBox CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName`

Comment: @HansUp I've updated my answer to include that. Are there any notable cons to using Wscript.Network?

Comment: None that I'm aware of.  I use it instead of the API functions.

Comment: FWIW, it's just as easy to spoof calls to `GetUserNameA` as it is to spoof calls to `rtcEnvironVar`.